# .NET micro framework + ARM howto

Tags: .net, embedded, arm, .net-micro-framework

How do I install the .NET micro framework on an ARM board?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific I'm afraid...

Comment: This cannot be answered without details of the hardware you want to use.

Comment: I got a windows host machine and an ARM9 based evalution board AT91SAM9RL i want to setup the netmf on the board.

Comment: Are you trying to port .net micro framework to some new ARM board, or asking for instructions how to install already ported .net micro framework for some specific board which supports it?

Comment: well i am really new to such porting & cross compiling stuff. I guess in general i mean installing an already ported .netfw, but it would be good too if i could learn how to port it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no generic "ARM installer" for the micro framework. ARM hardware can be very different from one processor to another, so in general you need to port it (i.e. rewrite hardware-specific parts for your device). Check out "Beginners Guide to Porting NETMF" [here](http://www.tinyclr.com/dl/).

Comment: I checked out that guide already, but somehow the mfdeploy tool won´t connect to my board.

Comment: my bad, i was not on the porting guide from tinyclr. Now I am there at chapter 8.1 but when i compile the tinyclr solution for my board (SAM9RL64) with CS Lite 2007. i am getting undefined reference to hal_vfprint error. I am using .netfm porting kit 4.0

Answer (score 0):

If I would guess that you are on a [Netduino](http://www.makershed.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=MKND01) ARM based board, you can take a look at [Pete Browns](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/09/02/first-experiences-with-netduino-and-the-net-micro-framework) guide, or the [Make guide](http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2010/08/new_in_the_maker_shed_netduino_a_ne.html#more). You have to install the device driver for the specific board, and the deployment takes care of the rest.